# Invalid constant character when using switch/case?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I cannot seem to make my code work properly. I need to find the area of the square and add the units of measurement depending on what the user uses either in for inch, m for meter, cm for centimeter, and ft for feet.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

// create scanner to read the input

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//prompt the user to enter one side of the length

       System.out.println("Enter one side of lenght of the square:");

        double side1 = sc.nextDouble();

        while (side1 < 0)

        {
//prompt the user to enter the input again in a positive value

            System.out.println("Error, No Negative Number. Enter again:");

            side1 = sc.nextDouble();
        }
char unitsMeasurement;
// prompt the user to enter the measurement unit
char units = Character.toUpperCase(status.charAt(0));
String unitsMeasurement = "";

    **{
        switch(units)
        {
        case "in":
            unitsMeasurement = "inch"; break;
        case "cm":
            unitsMeasurement = "centimeter"; break;
        case "ft":
            unitsMeasurement = "feet"; break;
        case "m":
             unitsMeasurement = "meter"; break;

        default:System.out.println("Invaild unit"); break;
                         }**


//Area of Square = side*side

          double area = side1*side1; 


        **System.out.println("Area of Square is: "+area, +unitsMeasurement+);**

      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error that you have encountered in the question text. Make sure it's the exact error message. From the title, I think you might have missed importing a java package. Try adding import java.lang.*;

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is, that you are using a switch-case-statement on a `char` while all your cases are based on a `String`. That doesn't work together. 
Some other problems are that `status` is never defined, therefore `units` can't have a value at all.

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but I assume the following: 
The user inputs the length of a square with a unit (abbreviated). The program calculates the area of the square and outputs it together with the unit (unabbreviated).

Sample input:

```
5cm
```

Sample output:

```
Area of square is: 25 centimeter^2
```

Keep in mind that an area has a squared length unit!

Based on that, here is some working code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    // create scanner to read the input
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //prompt the user to enter one side of the length
    System.out.println("Enter one side of lenght of the square:");
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    //Remove anything but digits
    double side1 = Double.parseDouble(input.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
    //Remove all digits
    String unit = input.replaceAll("\\d","");
    System.out.println(side1);
    System.out.println(unit);

    while (side1 < 0) {
        //prompt the user to enter the input again in a positive value
        System.out.println("Error, No Negative Number. Enter again:");
        input = sc.nextLine();

        //Remove anything but digits
        side1 = Double.parseDouble(input.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
    }

    switch(unit) {
        case "in":
            unit = "inch";
            break;
        case "cm":
            unit = "centimeter";
            break;
        case "ft":
            unit = "feet";
            break;
        case "m":
            unit = "meter";
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invaild unit");
            break;
    }

    double area = side1*side1;
    System.out.println("Area of Square is: " + area + " " + unit + "^2");
}
```